# How to install VIM plugin vim2hs with Vundle

Tags: haskell, vim

Here is my .vimrc file below. I have added the vim2hs plugin and run BundleInstall in VIM Normal mode

.vimrc

```
 " My Bundles here:
     Bundle 'dag/vim2hs'
```

I still see no syntax highlighting in my haskell files. Why is this?

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
 filetype off                   " required!

 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
 call vundle#rc()

 " let Vundle manage Vundle
 " required!
 Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

 " My Bundles here:
 Bundle 'dag/vim2hs'
```

Comment: What does `:echo &filetype` show in your haskell files? Do your other vundle plugins work?

Comment: Do you have `syntax on` in your .vimrc?

Comment: here is what my .vimrc looks like https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10021156/hi.txt

Comment: Anywhere in the vimrc, or just use `:syn on` in the haskell file. You may also want to set a `colorscheme`, but a default is provided.

Comment: Wow, that did it :) You the man. Put the answer and I'll mark yours correct.

Comment: No prob, I was over thinking it since I assumed you had that set. Welcome to vim and enjoy your stay -- you won't regret it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `syntax on` in your ~/.vimrc. This turns on syntax highlighting for vim. You may also want to check that you have the correct filetype set for your haskell files. `:echo &filetype` should report with `haskell`. Most users download and set a `colorscheme` (see `:help colorscheme`) to make the syntax highlighting more pleasant.

Comment: how do I make the semicolons look cool like they do in this picture? https://raw.github.com/dag/vim2hs/master/screenshots/bindings.png

Comment: That's just the font he's using.

Comment: thats not haskell syntax though. It says he's using something called conceal_wide. "In this screenshot, "wide conceals" are enabled, which is what makes the type colons and function arrows display as unicode. This option is disabled by default, since it can mess up the visual alignment between lines." To enable it like I have done here, try this:

let g:haskell_conceal_wide = 1. Where do I put this?

Comment: In your .vimrc before you call the Bundle for vim2hs.

Comment: I added it, but no dice. Semi-colons still look the same, as do arrows.

Comment: You might need `set encoding=utf-8` in your vimrc at the beginning and a utf-8 compatible font.

Comment: still no luck. Not sure if I need to reset vim or something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15448/discussion-between-conner-and-dave)

Comment: @Dave, make sure your vim is compiled with conceal. Try `:echo has("conceal")` and see if it returns 0 or 1.

Comment: No, that's why the vim2hs conceal stuff is not working. Your version of vim isn't compiled with +conceal.

Comment: You'll have to compile one with conceal or do without it.

Comment: is there an easy way to recompile? Should I use gvim?

Comment: I would [compile MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Building). It will automatically compile a terminal version with it that you can use as well.

Comment: I used `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp`